# Rails: Jquery Ajax issue with slidetoggle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a comment section that is apart of a micropost and I am trying to click a button within the micropost so that the comment section which is displayed as none in the CSS slides and shows. The problem is that all 10 micropost's comment button opens the most recent micropost when it should be opening it's own comment section of the micropost. I am unsure how to change the javascript around along with the HTML to make the comment button dynamic to it's own micropost. Here is what I am working with, any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

**JS**

```
$(".CommentTitle").click(function(){
    $("#CommentContainer").slideToggle("slow", function(){ 
        $(".CommentTitle").html($(this).is(":hidden") ? "Comments" : "Comments");  
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='Actions'>
<div class='CommentButton'>
<span class='CommentIcon'></span>
<span class='CommentNum'>5</span>
<span class='CommentTitle'>Comments</span>
</div>
</div>

<div id='CommentContainer' class='<%= micropost.id%>'>
<div class='Comment'>
<%=render "comments/form" %>
</div>
<div id='comments'>
<%=render @micropost.comments %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your HTML so that you don't have duplicate IDs on your CommentContainer elements. That is why jQuery is only finding the first one - you are creating invalid HTML.

Assuming you have one Comment button per micropost, you should add the micropost id as a data attribute to the Title, and retrieve that to find the correct CommentContainer. Each comment container should include the ID of the micropost it belongs to in it's ID.

HTML:

```
<div class='Actions'>
    <div class='CommentButton'>
        <span class='CommentIcon'></span>
        <span class='CommentNum'>5</span>
        <span class='CommentTitle' data-micropost='<%= micropost.id %>'>Comments</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='CommentContainer-<%= micropost.id%>' class='CommentContainer'>
    <div class='Comment'>
        <%=render "comments/form" %>
    </div>
    <div id='comments'>
        <%=render @micropost.comments %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javscript:

```
$(".CommentTitle").click(function(){
    var title = this;
    var postID = $(this).data('micropost');
    $("#CommentContainer-" + postID).slideToggle("slow", function(){ 
        $(".CommentTitle", title).html($(this).is(":hidden") ? "Comments" : "Comments");  
    }); 
});
```

Change your CSS to hide .CommentContainer instead of #CommentContainer

Comment: Hmmm it seems to not work, also the CommentContainer was hidden by CSS but with the addition of the `-<%= micropost.id%>` the CSS can't hide it, mmm not too sure waht is wrong

Comment: You seem to have classes and IDs very mixed up. CSS classes can apply to any element, and you can apply multiple classes to a single element. An element can only have one id property, and it has to be unique on the page. Change your CSS from `#CommentContainer { display:none; }` to `.CommentContainer { display: none; }`

Comment: mmm although I changed it to a class rather than an id the commentcontainer has a - and a postid on it so isn't the HTML not picking up on the CSS that is specified for commentcontainer only?

Comment: I added `class="CommentContainer"` as well as setting the id to 'CommentContainer-<%=PostID%>', so .CommentContainer CSS styles should apply to all of them

Comment: I have done everything you have said, I changed the JS and the class, id and the HTML, it hides the container now but does not open any when clicked upon, sorry for so much trouble and I really appreciate your help, alot! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".CommentTitle").click(function(){
    $("#CommentContainer", this.parent()).slideToggle("slow", function(){ 
        $(".CommentTitle", this).html($(this).is(":hidden") ? "Comments" : "Comments");  
    }); 
});
```

You can add a context to a jQuery selector, so that it will only match below that element. In this instance, I've added `this.parent()` to the container selector so it will only match #CommentContainer inside the clicked container, and this to the title selector so it will match the title within the current container.

This assumes your micropost HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id='#CommentContainer'>
  <span class='CommentTitle'>Some clickable title</span>
  <p>data here</p>
</div>
```

The element types don't matter, just that CommentTitle is a direct child of CommentContainer.

Comment: Can you take a look at the edit of the HTML, the Action's div contains the button and not the commentcontainer div because that is hidden by CSS, is there another way around this? Should I add another div tag around both the action and commentcontainer?

Comment: Will add another answer with my full recommendation in a sec.

Comment: you have been awesome help! I found out your code works but to my stupidity I wasn't adding the unobtrusive js files x) forgive me. Once again THANK YOU :)